# Want to get DateTime where I "dragged and dropped" Record from ListGrid to Calendar widget in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Can Anybody help me in this?

I want to get the ***Datetime*** where I dropped **Record** on **SmartGWT calendar widget**.

Details :

I have one **SmartGWT ListGrid** and one **SmartGWT Calendar**. Now I am able to **drag and drop *Record*** from **ListGrid** to **Calendar**. I am able to get other details of Record by ***Calendar.addDropHandler*** but I want the ***DateTime*** where I **dragged and dropped** that **Record**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get date time where I dropped the record on SmartGWT Calendar widget.

I can get that date using **calendar.getActiveTime()**. method.

But still I couldn't get the exact time where I dropped the Record. Calendar widget uses 30 minutes' time slice.

So if you dropped record at 12:33 PM then you will get 12:30 PM as dropped date time. So still there is no perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SmartGWT 4

I just found out that I could refine subdivision with 
`planning.setEventSnapGap(10);`.

Documentation would guide you through.